# What is Microsoft SQL server and why do I need to install it?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

All I want to install is visual web developer (but I've had this issue with other things like visual C# to), so when I choose to install just that from [microsoft web platform](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=VWD), it wants to download that, under 3mb, and SQL server (dependency it says,) 100mb. I've seen lots of computers with SQL server installed, does it come with all windows distributions? Do many other applications use it to work? Should I just install it if part of visual studio wants me to? When it asks me to make an administrator account and password for it, should I just type in whatever to get it to install as I won't be using it directly?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you don't need it. When the time comes that you know what it is, you can evaluate whether you do need it.

Comment: with that rep score, is this a serious question or a hacked account?

Comment: This question and its answers don't really cover what I was hoping to find when I searched for it (and yet Google directs me here no matter how I reword the question). What I'm curious about is, does Visual Studio use SQL Server **internally**? I'll probably never use SQL for the development I'm doing. I did an experiment and uninstalled SQL Server on a machine once, it seemed to work okay but that particular install of VS had some performance issues that I was not able to find the cause of, and I'm not sure if it was caused by SQL Server being absent or not.

Answer (score 8):

> What is it?

It is a [database system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_server).

> does it come with all windows
>   distributions?

No.

> Do many other applications use it to
>   work?

Yes.

> Should I just install it if part of
>   visual studio wants me to?

Yes.  It will hook everything up for you to a copy of [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx), so no further configuration will be required to make it work.

> When it asks me to make an
>   administrator account and password for
>   it, should I just type in whatever to
>   get it to install as I won't be using
>   it directly?

Yes.  Remember the user name and password for later use, but you will probably be using Windows Authentication to access SQL Server on your own machine, so you won't need this user name and password on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is installed along with Visual Studio is because SQL Server is a database system for storing data, and many developers these days are writing applications that work with databases, so the developer often needs a SQL Server installed so that he has a database system to develop and test against.  So in a nutshell, if you were writing such an application, you would already know what it is, and would know that you need it.  Which is why OrbMan said "If you don't know what it is, you don't need it."

If you get in the mood to learn something new though, I would highly recommend reading about SQL and SQL Server.  It is used alot in the real world.